# Permissions needed to run the Azure DevOps Migration Tools

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

What permissions do I need in source and target to run the Azure DevOps Migration Tools?

I've tried to find the information here and in the docs without success.

Edit:
I found something about adding my account to the Project Collection Service Accounts group which is basically same as Collection Admin. But docs also says this is not needed for "VSTS" (Azure DevOps Services). So still dont know what is needed when targeting Azure DevOps Services...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how you have your Azure DevOps Migration Tools run configured.

The account that you run the migration under will need to have permission to everything that you're accessing.

For example, if you are just running the **WorkItemMigrationConfig** and migrating work items only (not Area Paths, Iterations, or Tests), you could get away with only having **contribute** permissions within the **destination** project and **reader** permissions within the **source**.

However, I'd recommend making sure that the account you're using has at least **Project Administrator** rights within both the source and destination repositories to avoid any issues.

Comment: Thank you, that aligns well with what others have told me and what I have experienced so far. One more thing to add is that you need a proper license as well. You cannot create tags as a stakeholder for instance... and it is very likely that some of the work items you migrate will be tagged.

Comment: Yep! That's correct, the user will need a Basic license or greater.